# Trigger JQuery function/file in every EJS loop pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

How can I trigger jQuery in every EJS loop pass? There is a jQuery running backend of the EJS file.

Example:

```
<% for (var i=0; i<round16.length; i++) {  %>

    // round16 is an array.
    <DIV><%- round16[i][1] %></DIV>  // printing the round16 1st value 
    <DIV><%- round16[i][4] %></DIV>  // printing the round16 4th value 

    <div id="Team1Value6" style="display: none;"><%- round16[i][6] %> </div>

    <DIV class="inputValue6"><%- value6 %></DIV> 
<% } %>
```

For `<%- value6  %>`,  I want to take the dynamic value populated from the JS file running in the backend taking the input from round16[i][6].

But, it is printing the first value only in all the loop pass.
(because the JS function executes only once probably).

I want to print the value dynamically taking it from the backend JS file.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access an array of arrays. If I were to guess, I'd say your array is not actually setup the way you're trying to access it.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your reply. The round16  - 1st value and 4th value are printing properly as expected.  But for 6th value i have a API call through which the 6th value will print. in "class = inputValue6"  place. which is priting the first API received entry in all the loop pass.